# What happens if I set an int equal to the sum of the 2 largest ints?

Tags: c++

```
int sum;
```

The largest number represented by an int N is 2^0 + 2^1 + ... + 2^(sizeof(int)*8-1). What happens if I set sum = N + N? I'm somewhat new to programming, just so you new.

Comment: [Integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

Comment: What happens if you try it and see for yourself?

Comment: [Alternate article](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/DE18T05o/), specific to C++.

Comment: @nhgrif: If you try it yourself, you'll very likely get a wrapped result with no apparent error. In fact, the behavior is undefined; no experiment with actual code will demonstrate that.

Comment: @KeithThompson: well, if you can find a platform on which it crashes then you could make an educated guess that's the result of undefined behavior, rather than the standard specifically dictating that it must crash ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: Undefined behavior is not limited to crashing (in fact it's not limited at all). See my answer for an example.

Comment: @KeithThompson I think that a crash does imply undefined behavior (not the other way around, certainly), that was what Steve was referring to. (Or is a program without UB permitted to crash?)

Comment: @H2CO3: Depends on how you define "crash"; see `abort()`.

Comment: @KeithThompson For me, "crash" is an unexpected erroneous termination. If I call `abort()`, I do expect the termination.

Answer (score 4):

If the result of an `int` addition exceeds the range of values that can be represented in an `int` (`INT_MIN` .. `INT_MAX`), you have an *overflow*.

For signed integer types, the behavior of integer overflow is undefined.

On many implementations, you'll *usually* get a result that's consistent with ignoring all but the low-order N bits of the mathematical result (where N is the number of bits in an `int`) -- but the language does not guarantee that.

Furthermore, a compiler is permitted to *assume* that your code's behavior is defined, and to perform optimizations based on that assumption.

For example, with clang++ 3.0, this program:

```
#include <climits>
#include <iostream>

int max() { return INT_MAX; }

int main()
{
    int x = max();
    int y = x + 1;
    if (x < y) {
        std::cout << x << " < " << y << "\n";
    }
}
```

prints nothing when compiled with `-O0`, but prints

```
2147483647 < -2147483648
```

when compiled with `-O1` or higher.

Summary: Don't do that.

(Incidentally, the largest representable value of type `int` is more simply expressed as 2<sup>N-1</sup>-1, where N is the width in bits of type `int` -- or even more simply as `INT_MAX`. For a typical system with 32-bit `int`, that's 2<sup>31</sup>-1, or `2147483647`. You're also assuming that `sizeof` is in units of 8 bits; in fact it's in units of `CHAR_BIT` bits, where `CHAR_BIT` is *at least* 8, but can (very rarely) be larger.)

Comment: What's the behavior for unsigned types in spec? wrapping the value?

Comment: @H2CO3: Do you mean for `max()+10`, it _Modulo-2_ the result for `max()+1`, then adds remaining `9` to this result?

Comment: @MM.: For unsigned arithmetic, if the mathematical result is outside the range of the type, it's reduced module 2**N (where N is the width of the type). For example, `INT_MAX + 1` has undefined behavior, but `UINT_MAX + 1 == 0`. 2's-complement does not apply to unsigned types; it's a way of representing *signed* values.

Comment: @MM. No, it doesn't. It takes the whole thing as it would be if it didn't overflow, then it takes the final result modulo `2 ^ width`.

Answer (score 0):

you will have an integer overflow as the number will be too big for `int` if you want to do this you will have to declare it as a `long`

Hope this helps